# Let $C[a,b]$ be the set of continuous functions. Show that $\psi : C[a,b] \to \Bbb{R}, \psi(f) = \int_{a}^{b}f(x) \ dx$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $C[a,b]$ be the set of continuous functions with the sup norm. Show that $\psi : C[a,b] \to \Bbb{R}, \psi(f) = \int_{a}^{b}f(x) \ dx$ is continuous.

I have that $\forall \varepsilon >0 $ there exists $\delta >0$ s.t $\|f-g\|<\delta \implies |\psi(f)-\psi(g)| < \varepsilon.$ Now $$|\psi(f)-\psi(g)|=|\int_{a}^{b}f(x) \ dx - \int_{a}^{b}g(x) \ dx| \leqslant |\int_{a}^{b}f(x) -g(x) \ dx| \leqslant \int_{a}^{b}|f(x)-g(x)|\ dx$$

but I'm not sure how I can continue from here. What should I do to find $\delta$ that would work here?

Comment: Almost there: for every $x\in[a,b]$, we have the trivial estimate $|f(x)-g(x)|\leq \lVert f-g \rVert_{\infty}$ (the sup norm). This in fact shows the mapping $\psi$ is Lipschitz (which as you may know implies uniform continuity, and hence also continuity).

Comment: But what is the Lipschitz constant? The integral $\int_{a}^{b} \ dx = (b-a)$?

Comment: exactly it is Lipschitz continuous with $b-a$ (or anything larger than this) as a LIpschitz constant.

Comment: So I actually don't even need to use the $(\varepsilon, \delta)$ definition since $\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)-g(x)|\ dx \leqslant \int_{a}^{b}\|f-g\| \ dx \leqslant (b-a)\|f-g\|?$

Comment: Depends how much stuff you want to assume. If you already know Lipschitz implies (uniform) continuity then yes, it's enough to just say " for every $f,g\in C([a,b])$, $|\psi(f)-\psi(g)|=\left|\int_a^bf(x)-g(x)\,dx\right|\leq (b-a)\lVert f-g\rVert_{\infty}$, hence continuity follows". If you don't want to assume "Lipschitz implies continuity", then of course you'll need to use $\epsilon,\delta$ (though once you have the estimate I wrote, you'll essentially be proving that "Lipschitz implies continuous"). Anyway, this is trivial: given $\epsilon>0$, $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{(b-a)+1}$ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sequences: Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $C[a,b]$ and $f \in C[a,b]$ such that $||f_n-f||_{\infty} \to 0.$ That means that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to$f$.

Thus

$$\int_{a}^{b}f_n(x) \ dx \to \int_{a}^{b}f(x) \ dx .$$

This means

$$ \psi(f_n) \to  \psi(f).$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $a \neq b$, then pick $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{(b-a)}$. We want to show $\|f-g\|_{\infty}<\delta \implies |\psi(f)-\psi(g)| < \varepsilon.$ Indeed notice that:
$$|\psi(f)-\psi(g)|=|\int_{a}^{b}f(x) \ dx - \int_{a}^{b}g(x) \ dx| =|\int_{a}^{b}f(x) -g(x) \ dx| \leqslant \int_{a}^{b}|f(x)-g(x)|\ dx \leq (b-a) ||f-g||_{\infty} \leq (b-a) \frac{\varepsilon}{(b-a)} = \varepsilon $$